# Delete image from Firebase Storage using Angular 9

Tags: angular

`Can you help delete an image from Firebase Storage.
My code is as follows, but it does not delete the image from Storage:

import { AngularFireStorage} from '@angular/fire/storage';
.........
private storage: AngularFireStorage
..........
`deleteImage(photoo) {
return this.storage.storage.refFromURL(photoo).delete();
}

```html
 <div class="col-md-3 bodyshadow center" *ngFor="let photo of photoo">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <a (click)="delete_photo(photo.id)" placement="bottom" mdbTooltip="Delete " class="btn btn-danger btn-block"><i style="color: #fff" class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <img src="{{photo.downloadURL}}" class="card-img-top" alt="..."/>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component

```
constructor(private photoService: yourService) { } 
async ngOnInit() {
   await this.photoService.getAll()
      .then(response => {
        this.AllCard = response;
      }).catch(err => console.log("some error: ", err);)
  }
async deletePhoto(photoId) {
    this.photoService.deletePhoto(photoId)
      .then(async response => {
        console.log("response: ", response);
         await this.photoService.getAll()
      .then(response => {
        this.AllCard = response;
      }).catch(err => console.log("some error: ", err);)
      }).catch(err => console.log("some error: ", err);)
  }
```

In your service

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

deletePhoto(photoId) {
 const storageRef = db.storage().ref();
 storageRef.child('photo/' + photoId).delete();
  }
```

> I assume; that you will have installed the libraries, configured the
> connection to the database.

Comment: i want to delete image from storage. now i can delete them from my database but still in the storage

Comment: by using this. db.storage.refFromURL('photo/' + photoId).delete();